# The method 'load' was called on null. error while trying to show banner add with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

I was trying to put the banner ad on my homepage everything works fine but before the app starts I get a:

```
 The method 'load' was called on null.
 Receiver: null
 Tried calling: load()
```

The app opens and it shows the banner with the test ad but I want to know the reason behind this error.
here is my code:

```dart
    class Acilis extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _AcilisState createState() => _AcilisState();
    }
    
    class _AcilisState extends State<Acilis> {
      BannerAd banner;
      @override
      void didChangeDependencies() {
        // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
        super.didChangeDependencies();
        final adState = Provider.of<AdState>(context);
        adState.initialization.then((status) {
          setState(() {
            banner = BannerAd(
                size: AdSize.banner,
                adUnitId: adState.bannerAdUnitId,
                listener: adState.adlistener,
                request: AdRequest())
              ..load();
          });
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        banner.load();
         return Material(
```

```dart
Container(
 height: 50,
 child: AdWidget(ad: banner),
),
```

I skim the no relevant code here. this is the only two place that has the code of the banner. there is also an Admob_Service.dart file with the Ad State Class:

```dart
 import 'dart:io';
    
    import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
    
    class AdState {
      Future<InitializationStatus> initialization;
    
      AdState(this.initialization);
    
      String get bannerAdUnitId => Platform.isAndroid
          ? 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111'
          : 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111'; //test id
    
      BannerAdListener get adlistener => _adListener;
    
      BannerAdListener _adListener = BannerAdListener(
          onAdLoaded: (ad) => print('Ad Loaded'),
          onAdClosed: (ad) => print('Ad Closed'),
          onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) => print('Ad failed to load'),
          onAdOpened: (ad) => print('Ad Opened'));
    }
```

Comment: Uhm seems like the problem is ` banner.load();` method, because you was put it to build method before returning exact material. and `didChangeDependencies` can't run first, all of the time build methods will run first. So when you build your tree your `banner` will be null. That's why you get this error.

Comment: so should i put ` banner.load();' right before i the Container will it be solved?

Comment: or where should i put it? because the flutter doesnt let me put it on before container

Comment: Okay let me think, or just tell me exactly what you want, and I will think about that

Comment: I want a bannerAd at the bottom of the page as the last widget. this was my attempt so far. thank you so much!!

Comment: I never had used it before so probably I can't say anything about the banner. But, just remove your `banner.load();` from there, It's really wrong, you shouldn't call it when you build all the widget trees. Put it somewhere you do such a same thing like zero to one building something.